# Why does an image adjust to the width of the parent, but not to the height?

Tags: html, css

An image can adapt to the width of the parent with this code:

```css
#img-parent {
  max-width: 100px;
}


#header-img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="img-parent">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/09/16/22/23/yellow-183052_1280.png" id="header-img" alt="">
</div>
```

But it doesn't care if I set the height of the parent container:

```css
#img-parent {
  max-height: 100px;
}


#header-img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="img-parent">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/09/16/22/23/yellow-183052_1280.png" id="header-img" alt="">
</div>
```

Why does this happen, and how can I make the image adapt to the parent's height?

Comment: Set a `height` value for the parent, not just `max-height`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As the comment from TylerH said, the solution is to define the `height` of the parent, not just the `max-height`.